# XML parsing working fine with Android 2.2, 2.3 but not with ICS

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am fetching the some data from the server using XML parsing that is not working with ICS version of Android.here is my please tell me what correction do I make so that I should also run on ICS...(It's working fine with lower versions). Here is my code

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("file");

        namephoto = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("file");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            namephoto[i] = ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("name", "" + e);
    }
    photobitmap = new Bitmap[namephoto.length];

    setPhotoBackground(namephoto[index_photo]);
```

My XML code like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<root><file>1 a.JPG</file><file>2 b.JPG</file><file>3 c.JPG</file><file>4 d.JPG</file>  </root>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: getting `Null Pointer Exception`. exception occurs after this line `nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes()`

Comment: Does it work on Honeycomb 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have got the solution myself.. Here is the code which is compatible with Android 4.0 as well as rest of the android versions...Just change the for loop like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node name = nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList nodeEle = name.getChildNodes();
            namephoto[i] = ((Node) nodeEle.item(0)).getNodeValue();

        }
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much.This is problem what I have. I solved this now.